# Ruby on rails - Get data froma a remote DB without an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, remote-server

I'm trying to get data in a remote database from my app. I can do it with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({
  'adapter'=>'postgresql',
  'host'=> host_db,
  'port'=> port,
  'username'=> username_db,
  'password'=> password_db,
  'database'=> name_db
})
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(tiraSQL)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ENV['DATABASE']
```

But after the last line `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ENV['DATABASE']` all my tables become empty.

Is there any way that after the line I mentioned above the previos data in my model persists in a test enviorement (rspec)?

or

i can get the data from a database in other host but whitout changing my current **ActiveRecord::Base** connection.

Thnx in advance guys

Comment: Some server logs would be useful. You are defining the environment yourself in the last connection establishment - I suggest you check the environment in first database connection (`Rails.env`).

Answer (score 0):

Rails only keeps one database connection open at a time on ActiveRecord like that... So when you establish the connection, you are completely overwriting the old connection (to your local database).

You'll probably want to save the old connection somewhere, and return it after you connect to the new database... Then store the new connection somewhere. eg

```
old_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
new_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({
  'adapter'=>'postgresql',
  'host'=> host_db,
  'port'=> port,
  'username'=> username_db,
  'password'=> password_db,
  'database'=> name_db
})
data = new_connection.execute(tiraSQL)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection = old_connection
```

Note: I have not personally tested this code - you may well need to do something else to make it actually work.

Comment: Let us know if it works and if so, make sure to mark the answer as the correct solution - in case other people have the same problem and come googling - it helps them to know that this is a valid solution.

Comment: hi @taryn-east 
I tested your code, but always the models reset their data  when i change the conection.

This happen when i'm doing test whit rspec.

My enviroment:
Rails 4.2.6
RSpec 3.7
  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-rails 3.7.2
  - rspec-support 3.7.1

Comment: oh... rspec always removes all data between tests... test-environment is special.